# Convert base64 string to image in C# on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, base64, windows-phone

I have a base64 string and I want convert that to an image and set the Source of an Image control to the result of that.

Normally I would do that using `Image.FromStream`, similar to this:

```
Image img;
byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

However, the `Image.FromStream` method **does not exist on Windows Phone**, and a casual search only turns up results that depend on that method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a method like this:

```
    public static BitmapImage base64image(string base64string)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

Add an image to your XAML, such as this:

```
    <Image x:Name="myWonderfulImage" />
```

You can then set the source, like this:

```
myWonderfulImage.Source = base64image(yourBase64string);
```