# Converting ByteArray to base64 on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, encoding, windows-phone, base64

I'm facing a tremendous problem using the base64 convertor. I am calling the standard base64 convert function on Windows Phone but the result always differs from the one expected on web converters and many other on Android and iOS platforms.

Basically I take an Image from the gallery or Camera and convert it to byte array. The the byte array is passed to convert method.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);
```

The resulting string should look like this :

```
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
```

But the result is being this

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCAADAAMDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD7d+FP7cn7UvwM+F/w5+Cfws+KJ8LfDH4PeBPCXwt+HPhn/hCvh3rf/CO+BPh/oNh4T8I6H/bPiLwlq/iDV/7J0DSdPsDqmu6rqes6gbf7XqmoXt9NPcylFFfy7/b+e/8AQ6zb/wAOOM/+XH+2X/EKfC7/AKNtwD/4h3Dv/wA7j//Z
```

It differs not so much, but it differs. 
The right one is generated using PHP. And the Windows phone is generated usingUNICODE encoding on image.

Does anyone know how where could be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this piece of code using the `WriteableBitmap`:

```
 public string GetBase64Encoding(BitmapImage imageUrl)
        {
        byte[] bytearray = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
            if (imageUrl == null)
                {

                }
            else
                {
                WriteableBitmap wbitmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)imageUrl);

                wbitmp.SaveJpeg(ms, 46, 38, 0, 100);

                bytearray = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        string str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray);

        return str;
        }
```

For more you could refer this too:

[Convert base64 string to image in C# on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539005/)

Hope it helps!