# Image from FileOpenPicker to Base64

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone, base64, bitmapimage

I am writing **Windows Phone 8.1 app (WINRT)**

I am picking a photo from gallery using **FileOpenPicker** and then in **ContinueFileOpenPicker**, how to convert it into Base64??

```
  public void ContinueFileOpenPicker(FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            var FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs_File = args.Files.FirstOrDefault();

//Convert to URI
//Convert to Image
//Convert to Base64


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Convert.ToBase64String` in order to convert the image into `Base64`:

- [Converting image to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874733/)
- [Convert base64 string to image in C# on Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539005/)

Comment: its not working as methods like StreamResourceInfo GetResourceStream, SaveJpeg are not available in Windows phone 8.1 (WINRT)

Comment: Tried out `BitmapPropertySet` for WinRT 8.1? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994558/compress-and-save-base64-image-on-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: Thankyou, but what is destFileStream in it?

Comment: IRandomAccessStreamObject ? how to pass bitmap image, or Uri to this method/task?

Comment: Lemme have a look in it and get back to you.