# Converting Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image to byte[] Windows phone8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

So to make it simple, I  have a Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image in my C# class that is named MyImage. I would like to convert it to byte[] so that I can store it to my database.I have no idea how to do this since the image is Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image and not System.Drawing.Image so I can't do something like this:

```
...
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
   return  ms.ToArray();
```

I would appreciate if someone could write down a simple "how to" code to do this because I just can't figure it out.

Comment: did you check this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539005/convert-base64-string-to-image-in-c-sharp-on-windows-phone  Btw.. I am not sure Gif format file is supported.

Comment: Look into the ImageSource on the Image control.  Use your tools while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using a bitmap image then

```
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YourImagePath", UriKind.Absolute));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(myImage);
wb.SaveJpeg(ms, myImage.PixelWidth, myImage.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

This works for Windows Phone But if you are writing code for Windows Store App would suggest you to modify it.

```
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("YourImagePath"));
RandomAccessStreamReference rasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource);
var streamWithContent = await rasr.OpenReadAsync();
byte[] buffer = new byte[streamWithContent.Size];
await streamWithContent.ReadAsync(buffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)streamWithContent.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
```

Comment: But, my image is created in memory. It's not in UI. so, the step myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yourimagepath")) is not valid for me. Can you help me in this?

Comment: Could you share a code snippet of exactly how you are creating in memory.

Comment: Simply, 

Image img = new Image();
img.maxDimension = 500;
img.HorizontalAlignment = Stretch.None;

I hope I am clear.

Comment: Any
 thoughts on how to convert this Image() to writablebitmap?